# how to use select class and action class in selenium with python in POM framework?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

Sorry in advance if this question has been asked before. But I am trying to understand if my select class implementation is accurate?

I am using POM for my testing and I have a class called HomePage() and below is the code

```
    class HomePage():
      def __init__(self, driver)
          self.driver = driver
          self.id_that_i_am_using = 'navDropDown1' #this id for dropdown
          self.link_text_path = 'Link Text' 
     
 # created function for clicking on DropdoWn and it does 
      def click_on_drop_down(self):
          self.driver.find_element(value=self.id_that_i_am_using).click()
    

# trying to create function for select class
  

    def select_class(self, select, driver):
        select = Select()
        self.driver.find_element(value=self.id_that_i_am_using).click()
        select.select_by_index(1)
```

The Error I am getting is below:

```
TypeError: selec_class() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'select' and 'driver'
```

```
here is where I am trying to call my select class:
```

```
def test_login_valid(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https:www.google.com")
    home_page = HomePage(driver)
    home_page.click_on_drop_down()
    home_page.select_class()
```

Comment: Since you didn't show us where you call `select_class`, there is little we can do.  That's where the problem lies.  But, there is no need to have any parameters at all, since you immediately overwrite the `select` parameter, and you already have `driver` in `self.driver`.

Comment: I am trying to call select_class in my test.py file.

Comment: Added the call code as well

Comment: OK, so the simple solution is to change the function header to `def select_class(self):`, but what are you going to do with the result?  Your function doesn't return anything, and you aren't storing the result of `find_element` anywhere.  What do you think `select` is going to select?

Comment: goal is: once clicked on dropdown (which it is doing so far), select the second value. Thats what I am having trouble with. Frankly speaking I am new to this and thats why asking the community for help

Comment: Well, you need to find the `<select>` item that you want to pick.  You're not doing that.  It sounds like your function merely takes action, so you don't need to return anything.